# A persisting element in all subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a finitely generated abelian group and $a$ be a nontrival element of $G$ contained in all nontrivial subgroups of $G$. Is $G$ necessarily cyclic?

Comment: $Q_{8}$ or something...

Comment: @Gina: Is $-1$ common in all subgroups of $Q_8$?

Comment: @QuangHoang: Putting your mouse over the down arrow shows the text "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." I completely understand the downvote.

Comment: So probably it is true in abelian case?

Comment: @user138171:It's the only element with order $2$, and by Cauchy's Lagrange's, every nontrivial subgroup must have element of order $2$.

Comment: It's not even true in the abelian case.

Comment: @Gina: what if $G$ has an odd order?

Comment: @QuangHoang: I think it should be true in abelian case. Since if the cyclic decomposition have at least 2, then there are trivially intersected subgroup.

Comment: I'm thinking the "centered product" of two copies of $\mathbb Z/p^2$ with identical $\mathbb Z/p$. Am I missing something?

Comment: For sure, a group with a "persistent element" must be a p-group, since if two different primes $p$,$q$ divide the order of $G$, the subgroups generated by an element of order $p$ and an element of order $q$ intersect trivially.

Comment: @QuangHoang: wouldn't that be just $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p}$? Or am I missing something? (never worked with central product before)

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863390/subgroup-contained-in-all-other-subgroups/863600#863600

Comment: @mesel: that's for abelian case only. The way it is currently phrased, this question is about the nonabelian case, even though the asker's comment indicate it might have been originally meant to be just abelian.

Comment: @mesel, Jack A'Aurizio: that question is on finite groups. I did not restrict the question to finite groups. btw, I do not disagree with restricting to abelian groups.

Comment: OK. So it's true for abelian case for obvious reason (which I failed to see). @Gina: that group is of order $p^3$ and is not abelian :-(.

Comment: @user13871: It doesn't need to be finite in the other question. By the way, I vote to close this for duplication.

Comment: @user138171: where did you see this question ?

Comment: @mesel: I encountered it while proving something.

Comment: @user138171: Is $G$ abelian ?

Comment: @mesel: yes. But I wondered if it is really needed.

Comment: @QuangHoang: It seems the proof there is based on finiteness.

Comment: The answer uses the same idea with @Gina's comment: Cyclic decomposition of finitely generated abelian group.

Comment: @QuangHoang: Gina's comment is complete proof in abelian case. That question is completely for finite case.

Comment: @bof: yes but it may contain a power of it (equal to $a$)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: nope, there are no counterexample with odd order. See my answer. In particular, $Q_{8}$ is indeed rather representative of the rest of all the possible counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's consider what is the condition such that $G$ would have such element $a$. For simplicity, only finite $G$ are examined.

First, $|G|$ must be a prime power, otherwise it is false by Cauchy's. Let $|G|=p^{n}$ ($p$ prime, $n\geq 1$). Then any abelian subgroup of $G$ must be cyclic, by the proof using cyclic decomposition as outline in the comment: for any nontrivial abelian subgroup $H$ of $G$, we can always do the cyclic decomposition $H=\mathbb{Z}_{k_{1}}\times \mathbb{Z}_{k_{2}}\times\ldots\mathbb{Z}_{k_{t}}$. If $t\geq 2$ then $H$ have 2 subgroups that intersect trivially: $\mathbb{Z}_{k_{1}}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{k_{2}}$ (or more correctly, their embedding in $H$), which in turn mean that they are both subgroup of $G$ that not both containing $a$. Hence $t=1$ so $H$ is cyclic.

By a theorem, http://books.google.com/books?id=0268b52ghcsC&pg=262#v=onepage&q&f=false all subgroup of a such group must be either cyclic or a generalized quarternion group. In particular, $G$ is either cyclic or a generalized quarternion group. Hence the only counterexample would be the generalized quarternion group:

$<x,y|x^{2n}=y^{4}=1,x^{n}=y^{2},y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}>$

Because $|G|=p^{n}$ this means $p=2$. Generalized quarternion group have order at least $8$. Hence $G$ is a generalized quarternion group with order $2^{n}$ for $n\geq 3$ are all the exception to the claim. Note that the only possible persistent element in those counterexample are the lone element with order $2$.

As for infinite $G$, I have no ideas. Note that every cyclic group must have finite order, as infinite cyclic group do not have persistant element. Also, just like above, we still have $a$ have order $p$ for some prime $p$, and so each element still have order a power of $p$. Hence $G$ is now an infinite $p$-group that is finitely generated. The existence of such a group is the famous nontrivial Burnside's problem. There is a theorem that prove such a group exist http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golod-Shafarevich_theorem but there is no guarantee (and in fact rather unlikely) that the group constructed by that theorem will have a persistent element. Hence I will leave this to the expert.

Now if we remove the requirement that the group have to be finitely generated, then an example can be found. Notice that you can embedded $Q_{4n}$ inside $Q_{4(2n)}$ (the generalized quarternion group). Hence by keep embedding like that, you get a chain of group (chain ordered by subset relation). Simply use take the union of the whole chain to get the infinite group you want.

Comment: that's interesting. But do you have any counterexample for infinite non-abelian case?

Comment: @user138171: nope, that's even tougher than the infamous Burnside's problem. However, I edited in the explanation why it is hard, and a counterexample when finitely generated requirement is removed.

Comment: I intend to ask this in mathoverflow. Thanks.

Comment: @user138171: well an early sign that this is going to be difficult is that there are no infinite abelian group that satisfy the requirement, so you can't even get a cylic group to fulfill the requirement. In fact, I suspect such a group cannot exist, cyclic or not.

Comment: [the question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177179/existence-of-an-infinite-finitely-generated-p-group-with-nontrivial-intersecti)

Comment: I accept this answer because of your comments above answering original and current question.

Comment: Another counter-example to the infinite-generated case is [Prufer Quasi-cyclic groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) (same idea, but with cyclic groups). With respect to finitely generated, infinite $p$-groups, Tarski monsters do not have persistent elements.

Answer (score 2):

The group $G$ is supposed to be abelian. The subgroup generated by the persistent element must be simple. The group can't have any other simple subgroups, because the sum of simple subgroups is a direct sum of simple groups. Also the group must be indecomposable, because the persistent element can't belong to both a direct summand and its complement.

If $H$ is the simple subgroup generated by the persistent element, it intersects non trivially every non zero subgroup, so it is essential. In particular, the injective envelope of $G$ is the same as the injective envelope of $H$, so it is the Prüfer $p$-group, where $p=|H|$, because the Prüfer groups are the only indecomposable divisible torsion groups.

In particular $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of a Prüfer group; if it is finitely generated, it is cyclic; otherwise it coincides with the Prüfer group.

Comment: Is $G$ abelian in your answer?!

Comment: @user138171 Yes, of course. Otherwise almost none of the argument would work.

Comment: "The subgroup generated by the persistent element must be simple" how can Prüfer group be simple?!

Comment: @user138171 The Prüfer group is not simple, but it has persistent elements, precisely those of order $p$. Where's the problem? The *subgroup generated by a persistent element* is simple.

Comment: no problem. that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Since $G$ is finitly generatet abelian group;

$$G\cong \mathbb Z^n\oplus \mathbb Z_{n_1}\oplus...\mathbb Z_{n_k}$$

From [the question;](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863390/subgroup-contained-in-all-other-subgroups/863600#863600) we have $G\cong \mathbb Z^n\oplus \mathbb Z_{n_i}$ where $n_i=p^n$.

since  intersection of components trivial in the direct sum, $G\cong \mathbb Z$ or $G\cong \mathbb Z_{p^n}$. But in $\mathbb Z$, there is no integer which is divisible by all primes so f0r all $n\in Z$ there exist $pZ$ which does not contain it. Thus the answer is same $G\cong \mathbb Z_{p^n}$.