# Showing that if the intersection of all subgroups other than $\langle e \rangle$ is not $\langle e \rangle$, then every element is of finite order

Tags: group-theory

This is problem 2 on page 46 of I. N. Herstein's *Topics in Algebra*.

> Let $G$ be a group such that the intersection of all its subgroups which are different from  $\langle e\rangle$ is a subgroup different from $\langle e\rangle$. Prove that every element in $G$ has finite order.

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879196/a-persisting-element-in-all-subgroups)

Comment: In case MSE doesn't notify you of edits, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Hint: Assume that not every element has finite order; i.e., that there is an element $a$ of infinite order.  What can you say about the intersection of the non-trivial subgroups of the cyclic subgroup $\langle a\rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler answer than my previous one:

Consider

$$H=\bigcap_{g\in G} \langle g\rangle$$

The intersection of cyclic groups is cyclic, so either

(1) $H=\langle h\rangle$ with $\text{ord}_G(h)=n<\infty$

(2) $H=\langle h\rangle\cong \Bbb Z$ whence $\langle h^2\rangle$ is a proper subgroup, contradicting that $H$ was the intersection of *all* cyclic subgroups of $G$.

So the intersection has finite order. Since $n\ne 1$ by assumption, every $g\in G$ has that $\langle h\rangle \le \langle g\rangle$, but every non-identity element of an infinite cyclic group has infinite order, and clearly $h\in\langle g\rangle$ does not, so $|\langle g\rangle|<\infty$

Comment: [Source for the isomorphism claim](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793735/prove-that-if-g-is-cyclic-and-infinite-then-g-is-isomorphic-to-mathbbz)

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_Additive_Group_of_Integers#:~:text=Every%20non%2Dtrivial%20subgroup%20of,has%20the%20form%20nZ.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \neq e$ be an element from that intersection. If $a^2=e$, then $a$ has order $2$. Otherwise, $a \in \langle a^2 \rangle$, so $a=a^{2k}$, for some integer $k$, which implies $a^{2k-1}=e$, so $a$ has finite order. Either way $a$ has finite order.

Now let $g \in G$ be arbitrary. Since $a \in \langle g \rangle$, it follows that $g^{\ell}=a$ for some integer $\ell$, so $g^{\ell \cdot \mathrm{ord}(a)}=e$, so the order of $g$ is finite.

Comment: The expression  " if $a$  is not of order $2$, then $a\in \langle a^2 \rangle$" is not correct, perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: @mesel According to the hypothesis, $a$ is contained in **any** nontrivial subgroup of $G.$ If $\mathrm{ord}(a) \neq 2,$ then $\langle a^2 \rangle$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $G$, and so $a \in \langle a^2 \rangle.$

Comment: Now, I see what you mean.