# On a finite group with unique minimal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

**EDIT:** Let $G$ be a finite group with a **unique** minimal subgroup.
Then we know that $G$ is a $p$-group. Let $p\neq2.$

Is it true that every subgroup $H\le G$ and every quotient $G/N$ have a unique minimal subgroup?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No. The quaternion group of order $8$ is a counter-example, which has the Klein $4$-group as a quotient.  However, I think it is true if the order of the group is odd since, in that case, the group is cyclic of order equal to a power of an odd prime number.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I missed an important hypotesis. I'm going to edit.

Comment: My problem is that the conclusion "the group is cyclic" is the one I'm searching for. Hence I can't use it! The question I posted, is useful in the induction part of the proof of this theorem.

Comment: @Joe: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879196/a-persisting-element-in-all-subgroups